# CSS img not direct child of

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'd like to select a `img` child of `#boardMostra` but not direct child of a tag `a`.

I tried this :

```
#boardMostra img :not(a img:first-child){
  ...
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only css way you could use is to set a property on `#boardMostra img` and neutralize it on `#boardMostra a > img`.

#### An example

```
<div>
    <img src="#" alt="#">
    <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#"></a>
</div>

div img { margin: 10px 20px; }
div a > img { margin: 0; }
```

**Explanation**

Why your example code doesn't work:

> The :not(X) property in CSS is a negation pseudo class and accepts a
>   simple selector1 as an argument. Essentially, just another selector of
>   any kind.
>
> :not matches an element that is not represented by the argument. **The
>   passed argument may not contain additonal selectors** or any
>   pseudo-element selectors.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/

Comment: Thank's you save my day

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

```
#boardMostra > img , #boardMostra :not(a) > img { ... }
```

The first part refers to `<img>`s that are direct descendants of #boardMostra.

The second part refers to all `<img>`s in #boardMostra that are direct descendants of *anything but* `<a>`

See an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/t4snrgz6/

#### Why I think this is better than the accepted answer

There are times when you don't want to manually write out the CSS for the alternative set. For example, I am using a plugin that has a bunch of CSS for `<code>` elements that are direct descendants of `<pre>` elements. I want to style `<code>` elements that are NOT direct descendants of `<pre>` *without messing with the plugin's CSS*. My solution allows me to do that, using `:not(pre) > code`